# Limit of a sequence - the sign of infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^7-2n^4-1}{n^4-3n^6+7}$$

which isn't very hard. I divided the numerator and the denominator by $n^7$. The problem is with the sign of infinity which I get. I can't use any advanced techniques. I can however use the following theorem:

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $a_n<0$ for all $n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/a_n)=-\infty$.

So to use it I need to prove first that for all $n$ (or at least for all but a finite number of elements)  $n^{-7}(n^4-3n^6+7)<0$. I can see that this is the case (because $-3n^6$ dominates the whole expression) but how can I prove it strictly?

Comment: You talked about dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^7$.  Would it be useful to divide by $n^6$ instead?

Comment: Or maybe divide by $n^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also factorize the nominator by $n^7$ and the denominator by $n^6$. Then,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^7-2n^4-1}{n^4-3n^6+7}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^7(1-2/n^3-1/n^7)}{n^6(-3+1/n^2+7/n^6)}=+\infty (-1/3)=-\infty$

Comment: Great idea! Thank you, sir.

Comment: I'm not a woman :)

Comment: Heh, I meant that I am a woman (a madam, that is) :)

Comment: I am sorry, my fault. Anyway, thank you for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use the long division to get $$\frac{n^7-2n^4-1}{n^4-3n^6+7}= \frac{n^7-2n^4-1}{-3n^6+n^4+7}=-\frac{n^7-2n^4-1}{3n^6-n^4-7}=-\frac{n}{3}-\frac{1}{9 n}+\frac{2}{3 n^2}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

what you need only to prove is $n^4-3n^6+7<0$ and to do this you can observe that for $n\geq 2$ $3n^2\geq 8$ and then:
$$3n^6\geq n^4(3n^2)\geq 8n^4> n^4+7 $$

and finally for all $n\geq 2$ we have $n^4-3n^6+7<0$

Comment: you're very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Set $\dfrac1n =h$ to get $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1-2h^3-h^7}{h^3-3h^4+7h^7}=+\infty$$ as $h\to0^+$